# Orchard.Layouts does not display all elements

Tags: orchardcms

Sometimes something happens and orchard layouts module starts incorrect working:

1. When I edit a content item that layout part does not display any layout element and canvas area.
2. When i view a content item that layout part does not display some layout elements, ex. projection elements.

In such cases I enable and disable output cache module that orchard layouts module starts correct working again.

I posted this message also to codeplex https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/21305 It is a critical error which prevents the normal working of production site. May be you have any idea what i should do?

One of the errors that got into the log

```
2015-03-31 09:08:38,594 [93] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - Default - NullReferenceException thrown from IContentPartDriver by Orchard.Layouts.Drivers.LayoutPartDriver
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.ElementFactory.Activate(ElementDescriptor descriptor, Action`1 initialize)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.ElementManager.ActivateElement(ElementDescriptor descriptor, Action`1 initialize)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.ContentModelMap.ToElement(IElementManager elementManager, DescribeElementsContext describeContext, JToken node)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.LoadElement(JToken node, Container parent, Int32 index, DescribeElementsContext describeContext)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.ParseEditorNode(JToken node, Container parent, Int32 index, DescribeElementsContext describeContext)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ParseEditorNode>b__d(JToken x, Int32 i)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.ParseEditorNode(JToken node, Container parent, Int32 index, DescribeElementsContext describeContext)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ParseEditorNode>b__d(JToken x, Int32 i)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.ParseEditorNode(JToken node, Container parent, Int32 index, DescribeElementsContext describeContext)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ParseEditorNode>b__d(JToken x, Int32 i)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.ParseEditorNode(JToken node, Container parent, Int32 index, DescribeElementsContext describeContext)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ParseEditorNode>b__d(JToken x, Int32 i)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.ParseEditorNode(JToken node, Container parent, Int32 index, DescribeElementsContext describeContext)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Services.LayoutModelMapper.<ToLayoutModel>d__6.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в Orchard.Layouts.Drivers.LayoutPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Editor>b__11()
   в Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShape>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) в d:\sites\orchard sites\rpa-mu.ru-2-new\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 196
   в Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__1a(BuildShapeContext ctx) в d:\sites\orchard sites\rpa-mu.ru-2-new\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 205
   в Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) в d:\sites\orchard sites\rpa-mu.ru-2-new\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line  45
   в Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildEditorContext context) в d:\sites\orchard sites\rpa-mu.ru-2-new\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs: line 25
   в Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClass10.<UpdateEditor>b__f(IContentPartDriver driver) в d:\sites\orchard sites\rpa-mu.ru-2-new\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 65
   в Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) в d:\sites\orchard sites\rpa-mu.ru-2-new\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
```

Comment: Can you please file a bug?

Comment: I created the issue. I added a new comment to issue Today http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/21305